# Cucumber JS can see my feature, but doesn't seem to run the steps

Tags: javascript, cucumber, gruntjs

I've set up Cucumber-JS and Grunt-JS within my solution.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
+ Project
  + features
    - Search.feature
    + step_definitions
      - Search_steps.js
    + support
      - world.js
  - package.json
  - gruntfile.js
```

I've added a Cucumber-JS task in gruntfile.js:

```
// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    cucumberjs: {
        src: 'features',
        options: {
            steps: 'features/step_definitions',
            format: 'pretty'
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-cucumber');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['cucumberjs']);
```

And I've written out my feature file:

```
Feature: Search
    As a user of the website
    I want to search
    So that I can view items

    Scenario: Searching for items
        Given I am on the website
        When I go to the homepage
        Then I should see a location search box
```

And my step definition file:

```
var SearchSteps = module.exports = function () {
    this.World = require('../support/world').World;

    this.Given('I am on the website', function(callback) {
        callback.pending();
    });

    this.When('I go to the homepage', function (callback) {
        callback.pending();
    });

    this.Then('I should see a location search box', function (callback) {
        callback.pending();
    });
};
```

And my world.js file:

```
var World = function (callback) {
    callback(this);
};

exports.World = World;
```

But when I run grunt at the command-line, while it seems to see my features, it never seems to run any of the steps.

All I get is this:

```
Running "cucumberjs:src" (cucumberjs) task
Feature: Search

  Scenario: Searching for items
    Given I am on the website
    When I go to the homepage
    Then I should see a location search box


1 scenario (1 pending)
3 steps (1 pending, 2 skipped)

Done, without errors.
```

Cucumber doesn't seem to pay any attention to what I put inside the tests.

Even if I put some obvious logical bug in, e.g.:

```
this.Given('I am on the website', function(callback) {
    var x = 0 / 0;
    callback.pending();
});
```

It just ignores it and prints the above message.

The only way I can seem to get any error out of Cucumber is to put an outright syntax error in the step file. E.g. remove a closing bracket. Then I get something like this:

```
Running "cucumberjs:src" (cucumberjs) task

C:\dev\Project\features\step_definitions\Search_steps.js:14
                };
                 ^
Warning: Unexpected token ; Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you show us the content of your world file? You might have forgotten to call back in its constructor.

Comment: @jbpros, I've updated the question to include the world.js file and the code that "require"s it. And yes, it does call back the constructor, but unfortunately still doesn't work.

Comment: Everything is running smoothly, actually. You call callback.pending() in your first step definition, telling cucumber you're not finished implementing it. Look at the output, it says there was one pending step and two skipped.

Comment: You need to call `callback()` instead. Pass it an error when you want Cucumber to report an error: `callback(new Error('I fail!'))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in my comments, everything is working as expected. Calling `callback.pending()` tells Cucumber your step definition is not ready yet and the rest of the scenario should be ignored for now.

Change that to `callback()` to tell Cucumber to move to the next step in the scenario. If you want to notify Cucumber of a failure, pass an error to that callback or throw an exception (I don't recommend that though):

```
callback(new Error('This is a failure'));
```

HTH.

Comment: Thanks! That's all I needed to know! For some reason, I never saw this in any of the cucumber-js documentation.

Comment: The documentation needs some love but it's burried in the README: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/README.md#step-definitions

Comment: @jbpros: Where this error message gets printed? I have created a wrong scenario and am throwing error, but no message gets printed on the command line. I have actually cloned your github repo only-- https://github.com/jbpros/cucumber-js-example and changed debug to true and then in google_land.js replaced `assert.ok(linksToUrl.length > 0);` with ` if (1==1){
        callback.fail(new Error("Forced error"));
        console.log("ERror");
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
this.World = require("../support/world.js").World;
```